# findOne is gaving me the same result for different IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a list of different Ids , and I'm trying to find the products that have those Ids and push them in another array.
The problem is that when I use findOne() return the same product for all Ids.

```js
let  wishpro = ['632a5e5rtybdaafd23','65fdaartbdqip55'];
            
            for(let i = 0; i < wishpro.length ; i++) {
                let x = await product.findOne({id : wishpro[i]});
                console.log("x : " + x.id )
                wishProducts.push(x);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findOne()` will return the first match that it finds. Instead, you can use `find()` with `$in` operator, and fetch all of the records with one query:

```js
const wishpro = ['632a5e5rtybdaafd23','65fdaartbdqip55'];

const result = await product.find({ id: { $in: wishpro } });
```